# Bokeh plot sort bar plot by values not by index

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, holoviews

I was going through bokeh tutorial from their official website: https://hub.mybinder.org/user/bokeh-bokeh-notebooks-tkmnntgc/notebooks/tutorial/00%20-%20Introduction%20and%20Setup.ipynb
and attempted to get a similar plot for crime rates in USA cities from
wikipedia data of 2009. But, I stuck with some problems.

First of all I searched related questions and they quite did not meet my
problems.

Related questions:
[Choosing order of bars in Bokeh bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135531/choosing-order-of-bars-in-bokeh-bar-chart)

**Questions**
1. How go get values at top of the vertical bars?
2. How to get the values sorted by y-axis values instead of x-label indices?

[image]

The code is given here:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
output_notebook()

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_cities_by_crime_rate"
response = requests.get(url)

df = pd.read_html(response.content)[1]
df = df.iloc[2:]
df.columns = ['State', 'City', 'Population', 'Total_violent',
              'Murder', 'Rape', 'Robbery', 'Assault',
              'Total_property', 'Burglary', 'Larceny', 'Motor_theft',
              'Arson']

df.index = df.index - 2  # Reset index numbers
df.index = df.City


# rename index
df.index.name = 'index'

# Change data type and sort
df['Murder'] = df['Murder'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df = df.sort_values(by='Murder', ascending=True)

# first and last 10
df = pd.concat([df.head(10), df.tail(10)])
df.index = range(20)

# create low_high column
df['low_high'] = ['low']*10 + ['high']*10

# create group of two x-axes
group = df.groupby(by=['low_high', 'City'])

# from group get source
source = ColumnDataSource(group)

# from group get figure
p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=300, 
           title="Murder in US city per 100,000 people in 2009",
           x_range=group, 
           toolbar_location=None, 
           tools="")

# plot labels
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Cities"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Murder"
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.2

# index_cmap will be used for fill_color
index_cmap = factor_cmap('low_high_City', 
                         palette=['#2b83ba', '#abdda4', '#ffffbf', '#fdae61', '#d7191c'], 
                         factors=df['low_high'].unique(), 
                         end=1)

p.vbar(x='low_high_City', 
       top='Murder_mean', 
       width=1, 
       source=source,
       line_color="white", 
       fill_color=index_cmap, 
       hover_line_color="darkgrey", 
       hover_fill_color=index_cmap)


hover_cols = ['Murder','Rape','Robbery','Assault','Burglary','Larceny','Motor_theft','Arson']
for col in hover_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')


tooltips = [(c,"@"+c+"_mean") for c in hover_cols]
tooltips = [("City","@City")] + tooltips
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips))

show(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order on the axis is determined entirely by the order of factors in the plot range:

[image]

If you want the factors to appear on the axis in a different order, you must simply sort this list to whatever order you want, and re-assign to the range:

```
p.x_range.factors = sorted_factors
```

For your case, here is one way to do it (I'm not a Pandas expert, there are probably much better ways):

```
desc = group.describe()

low_cities = desc.Murder['mean']['low'].index
low_sorted = [('low', city) for city in sorted(low_cities, key=lambda x: desc.Murder['mean'][('low',)][x])]

high_cities = desc.Murder['mean']['high'].index
high_sorted = [('high', city) for city in sorted(high_cities, key=lambda x: desc.Murder['mean'][('high',)][x])]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. but it Still did not work. I tried ```name_high = [('high', v) for v in df['City'].values[:10]]
name_low = [('low', v) for v in df['City'].values[10:]]

name_low_high =   name_high + name_low
print(name_low_high)

p.x_range.factors = name_low_high``` It gives empty image.

Comment: Also, in jupyter notebok (or jupyterlab or hub) how did you get dropdown menu at `p.x_range.factors`, I only get tab completions.

Comment: That sorting produces bad (non-existent) factor combinations, and has garbled the range. The original factors has `('low', 'Lincoln')` but your `name_low_high` has `('high', 'Lincoln')` which does not exist in the data. You need to sort the original factor tuples as they are.  I'm not sure what dropdown menu you are referring to, the image above is just an input cell and its output.

Comment: I've added an example specific to your case to the answer.

Comment: Awesome! It works perfectly now.  I forgot to sort key value pairs correctly while creating `p.x_range_factors`. Thanks a lot for your help. Bokeh is beautiful. Also, I like its successors `holoviews` and `pyviz`. The devs deserve respect and applause!

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind words!